# How do I connect to Oracle 10 from pyodbc?

Tags: python, oracle, odbc, pyodbc

I have "Oracle in OraClient10g" and "Microsoft ODBC for oracle" drivers (checked using ODBCAD32.EXE).

Is there a way to connect to the oracle database with pyodbc?

Comment: have you tried looking at [this](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/python/pyodbc.html)

Comment: yes i did, but it was not immediately obvious that was what I needed. I think now that odbc drivers are required for both the database side and the software side (oracle to python). so MS odbc drivers wont help me.

Comment: ive tried installing the pyodbc-oracle installer, but it doesnt install. windows says something is wrong with the installer.

Comment: If you don't have a requirement for using ODBC then CX_Oracle would be an alternative way to connect. It also supports more Oracle functionality than ODBC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Oracle drivers with DSN and for me it connects:

```
db = pyodbc.connect('DSN=my_test_db;PWD=tiger')

print('-' * 20)
try:
    c = db.cursor()
    rs = c.execute("select * from v$version where banner like 'Oracle%'")
    for txt in c.fetchall():
        print('%s' % (txt[0]))
finally:
    db.close()
```

Comment: this does not work... do i need to install anything to get dsn?

Comment: Have you configured TSN in NetManager (part of Oracle client)? Have you configured ODBC DSN in ODBCAD32.EXE?

Comment: I dont have access to the server. I have added a DSN for "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle". I get the error `The driver doesn't support the version of ODBC behavior that the application requested`

Comment: On your machine you must have Oracle client installed and configured, In your question there is info about "Oracle in OraClient10g" so you have Oracle client. Part of this client is NetManager and NetConfigurationAssistant. Have you used it to configure TNS? If not then read Oracle tutorials about configuring TNS.

Comment: given my lack of experience, I had no idea about TNS. consequently I was using the server in my connection string, when actually I should have been using the TNS "name". The error messages, unfortunately, sent me off in the wrong direction.